# Нужно ли ставить запятую в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Эти люди (,) словно из полицейского участка.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По общему правилу не требуется никакого знака ([здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92), пункт 1 примечание 2), но перед *словно* может стоять интонационное тире.

Comment: Мне не очень понятна ссылка на Розенталя. Здесь нет сказуемого в форме И.п., скорее это обстоятельственный оборот (из полицейского участка).